# Was there a policy of preemptive attack on foreign fleets in the British Empire?

Tags: british-empire

I heard many times that the British Empire had an official policy to attack anyone who was close to having a great flotilla able to challenge their sea dominance. I cannot find any sources about who declared this and when, how long it stood, and if it ever was an official policy.

Comment: You may be confusing the "Two powers policy" with the attack to the Danish fleet during the Napoleoninc wars or the attack to Mers-El-Kebir during WW II (all of them have nice wikipedia pages).

Comment: BBC History magazine's article on the sinking of the Bismarck mentioned this notion. Several articles about WWI mentioned the preemptive attack doctrine, but never cited it or attributed it.

Comment: The disgraceful British attacks on Denmark isn't dictated by doctrine - the responsible ministers never attempted to defend it as a matter of policy afaik. They were merely the ill conceived muscle flexing of a naval superpower that had ran out of actual foes after Trafalgar.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any such official policy. It would not have made much sense to deliberately and continuously start wars with other "great powers" of the time.

If you take, for example, the 1807 attack on Copenhagen, this was specifically motivated by reports that Napoleon was pressuring the Danes to use their fleet against the British or to give it to France. Napoleon had been engaging in war throughout Europe and had intended an invasion of England.

The British were not set on preemptive attack, they offered a more peaceful alternative that would place the Danish fleet out of Napoleon's reach:

> Canning offered Denmark a treaty of alliance and mutual defence, with a convention signed for the return of the fleet after the war, the protection of 21 British warships and a subsidy for how many soldiers Denmark kept standing.

The next day Napoleon demanded Denmark prepare for war against Britain or face French invasion.

Everything points to the attack on Copenhagen being a reaction to a specific threat rather than a specific application of a general policy.

Comment: Well, *reaction to a **perceived** and **fabricated** threat*. The Danes were no threat and was set to resist France until the treachery drove them into Napoleon's arms. But your point that it was ad hoc and not doctrinal is well made, +1.

Comment: The Danes _were_ a threat in that they had a fleet capable of standing up to the British Navy, had it been used before destruction. (Note my use of the word fleet and not navy. The ships were the threat, not so much the people.)

Comment: @CGCampbell It wasn't a threat in any practical sense of the word. The Danish navy could not even defend its capital. Remember, the Danes fought very well against Nelson himself in 1801, so it was certainly not the case that a French crew would suddenly empower a mere **18** ships of the line to challenge British naval hegemony. The Royal Navy had 175 ships of the line and 750 frigates/sloops by 1805.

Comment: Note that a very similar thing happened wrt the French fleet when the country capitulated to the Nazis. The Brits ordered all French capital ships to be either interred in friendly ports out of Nazi hands, or destroyed. ("Operation Catapult"). But this was more a tactical consideration that a political position. Technically they didn't have a "right" to do this, but this was a war, and they would have been really stupid to let the Nazis double their fleet this way.

Comment: @T.E.D. Also worth noting that the French scuttled their ships when the Germans attempted to take them over.

Comment: @Semaphore - Some of them, yes (eg: at port in Toulon). However, some French naval commanders (eg: at Mers-elKebir and the captain of the battleship [Richelieu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_battleship_Richelieu)) weren't feeling quite that solicitous to their former allies, so the issue had to be forced.

Comment: @Semaphore, The threat was that a hostile Danish fleet could cut off Baltic trade, the timber trade in particular. Baltic pine was the prefered source of timbers for ships' masts. Something that was of great importance to a fleet that spent so much time at sea. As such it was a direct threat to the British navy, out of proportion to the mere size of the Danish fleet. Also, I'd take that "175 ships of the line" with a pinch of salt, since it included ships that were under construction, under repair and in (permanent) harbour service.

Comment: @T.E.D. That makes no sense whatsoever. There was no German takeover attempt at Mers-el-Kébir, and the French there *did* also promise to scuttle their ships if there was. In fact the ships scuttled in Toulon *included* survivors of Mers-el-Kébir.

Comment: @SteveBird Which is not a real threat since Denmark wasn't hostile, and the Royal Navy was still more than capable of destroying any such blockade, 26 ships under construction or not.

Comment: @Semaphore you either missed my final sentence, or are willfully ignoring it. The Danish fleet wasn't much of a threat in the hands of its rightful owners (navy), I concede. But if that fleet of ships were given to, or taken over by Napoleon's admirals, it was certainly capable of causing notice at a time when Britain wanted to control the seas utterly, disproportionate to its size.

Comment: @CGCampbell You either missed my response or are wilfully ignoring it: "the Danes fought very well against Nelson himself in 1801, so it was certainly not the case that a French crew would empower...". France had 41 ships (incl Spainish) at Trafalgar. 18 Danish ships was hardly going to do any better. Now, I could agree if you argued it could cause problems acting as a Fleet in Being in the Baltics (but by alienating Denmark the RN had to send large escorts for the Baltic trade against privateers anyway). But the original claim it would be "capable of standing up to" the RN I find outlandish.

Comment: @Semaphore OK, I get what you're saying, really I do. However, either the Danish 'fleet' wasn't a threat, and Britain destroyed it (and fired Copenhagen) through willful malice alone, or it was a threat and they preemptively destroyed it, before it could cause any damage of any kind. Note that I don't believe in any acknowledged _or_ unacknowledged "policy of preemptive strikes against any other sea power"; I'm only saying that this attack WAS preemptive, because the Admiralty thought they (the fleet in question) were a threat, however insignificant.

Comment: @CGCampbell You may have misunderstood me. I agree it was pre-emptive, but disagree with the either-or. My argument has been that Britain (unnecessarily undiplomatically) eliminated a *perceived threat* which was *not* substantially real.